# Dependent clause after pronoun

Tags: grammar, word-usage, pronouns, relative-clauses

This question arose from why sentence #1 is correct and why sentence #2 is incorrect -

> I pity those who lost their money in gambling.
>
> I pity them who lost their money in gambling.

I have asked the question in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28876/those-who-vs-them-who) forum, as well as in [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8580/those-who-vs-them-who/8582?noredirect=1#comment20520_8582) forum.

But the answers their made me more confused.

**RULE 1**

> Jlawler's comment contains the direct answer to the question. Definite personal pronouns (I/me, you, he/him, she/her, it, we/us,
>   they/them) cannot take a restrictive modifier. In other words, they
>   cannot take a dependent that narrows the set of entities that they
>   denote. This trait of personal pronouns underlies their use as test
>   words for constituent structure. For example:
>
> ```
>  (a)  The man with the hat knows the woman with the scarf.
>
>  (b)  He knows her. 
>
>  (c) *He with the hat knows her with the scarf.
> ```
>
> Sentence (a) is the starting sentence. Sentence (b) shows proform
>   substitution; the personal pronouns *he* and *her* have been
>   substituted in for the noun phrases *the man with the hat* and *the
>   woman with the scarf*. Based on the acceptability of sentence (b), one
>   concludes that both *the man with the hat* and *the woman with the
>   scarf* are constituents. Definite pronouns such as *he* and *her* (and
>   *them*) take the place of constituents, in this case of complete noun phrases.
>
> The unacceptability of sentence (c) reveals that the strings *the man*
>   and *the woman* in (a) are not constituents. In other words, the
>   definite personal pronouns *he* and *her* cannot take dependents
>   (=modifiers), since they necessarily replace an entire noun phrase.
>   This fact explains why *them who lost their money* in the question is
>   bad English. The relative clause *who lost money* is a postdependent
>   (=postmodifier), and as such it cannot modify *them* (because *them*
>   as a definite personal pronoun cannot be modified).
>
> The plural demonstrative pronouns (*these* and *those*) behave
>   differently. They can take postdepndents (=postmodifiers, i.e. a
>   modifier that follows them), e.g
>
> ```
>  (d)  These with hats know those with scarves.
> ```
>
> This is simply a trait of the plural demonstrative pronouns (*these*
>   and *those*) -- there is no good explanation why plural demonstrative
>   pronouns behave differently than definite personal pronouns; they
>   simply do. Note that the plural demonstrative pronouns also behave
>   differently than the singular demonstrative pronouns in this regard,
>   e.g.
>
> ```
>  (e)  *This with a hat knows that with a scarf.
> ```
>
> Singular demonstrative pronouns (*this* and *that*) are behaving like
>   the definite personal pronouns; they cannot take dependents.
>
> The combination **plural demonstrative pronoun + restrictive relative
>   clause** can actually be viewed as a particular construction in
>   English and related languages. That is, it is a combination that
>   occurs relatively frequently and has therefore been lexicalized.
>   German has a very similar construction, e.g.
>
> ```
>  (f) Diejenigen mit einem Hut kennen diejenigen mit einem Schal. 
>      those      with  a   hat  know     those   with  a   scarf.
> ```
>
> By acknowledging that one has a particular construction, one is in a
>   sense admitting that there is no real grammatical "explanation" for
>   the phenomenon. It simply exists.
>
> Finally, note that there are certain apparent exceptions to the
>   principles mentioned above. There are uses of personal pronouns that
>   actually allow modification, e.g.
>
> ```
>  (g) He who studies a lot gets a good grade.
> ```
>
> In this example, the personal pronoun *he* is not referring directly
>   to a specific entity, which means it is not definite; it is, rather,
>   being used as an indefinite pronoun; it means 'the one, anyone', e.g.
>   *Anyone who studies a lot gets a good grade*.

**MY CONFUSION**

Reading this answer make the following sentence consider wrong -

> It is she who stood second in class.

So another person came up with another rule -

**RULE 2**

> Nominative personal pronouns can be modified by relative clauseas just
>   like demonstrative pronouns; it's the objective personal pronouns that
>   can't. *He who, she who, they who, you who* are all grammatical, if
>   archaic. *Him who, her who, them who*, however, aren't.

**MY CONFUSION**

Now this rule create a conflict with the rule 1 I quoted first. In the first rule it says - ***He with the hat knows her with the scarf*** - sentence is wrong, but if we consider the second rule then this particular sentence should be correct.

Another problem with the second rule is that it makes the following sentence incorrect -

> The action was performed by her who is the secretary of XYZ company.

So another rule came in picture -

**RULE 3**

> "Them," combined with the "who," has to be used with a preposition
>   like "to," "from," or "with."
>
> "I pity them," by itself, is a grammatically correct sentence, but
>   when you connect the dependent clause with "who," it is no longer
>   correct.

Now I am really confused. Can anyone here please help?

Comment: These sound natural: _I pity those people who lost their money in gambling_ (if no people have not been mentioned before) // _I pity those who lost their money in gambling_ (if this is a subset of people already mentioned). Using the version without 'people' when no people have been mentioned previously uses a very formal register. //// _I pity them who lost their money in gambling_ sounds 400 years out of date.

Comment: But ... *"The action was performed by her who is the secretary of XYZ company"* is wrong. At least it sounds so to me.

Comment: @PeterShor Someone say it's correct and someone say it's wrong. I am really confused. I want to know the grammatical explanation so that I wont make any mistake in using dependent clauses after pronouns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My first proposal would be to forget *Rule 2* and *Rule 3*, and use *Rule 1* with the additional rule that constructions with an existential *"it"* like *"it was he who ..."* are grammatical. But quite likely somebody will come up with an example showing that this isn't completely right.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks Peter. Another confusion - if in the sentence "The action was performed by her who was the secretary of XYZ company", the restrictive dependent clause is replaced by a non-restrictive dependent clause, will it be correct sentence?

Comment: I would consider it correct. It's possible that different native speakers of English, who speak different dialects, might disagree on this grammar.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks again. I am talking about the standard English.

Comment: Rule 2 seems correct to me. Firstly, your modification with *with a scarf* is not a relative clause. There is no relative pronoun heading the clause that stands for *her*. *With* is a preposition, it doesn't mean *her*. So the ungrammaticality is not to do with relative clauses. Secondly, ***The action was performed by her who is the secretary of XYZ company*** definitely sounds ungrammatical to me, and five of my colleagues, whom I've just tested it on. I'm guessing it's wrong in standard British English. The first and third rules won't hold.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret

> 1) "I pity them who lost their money in gambling"

as a reduction of

> 2) "I pity them -- those who lost their money in gambling"

or, with a minor variation of punctuation,

> 3) I pity them, those who lost their money in gambling.

Your query sentence 1) may not be regarded as Standard English written usage, but I think it's perfectly acceptable in conversation. It's a question of the register being used.

Comment: I would rather call it archaic than conversational, using _who_ in the sense “they who” or “whoever”. I could imagine someone like Tolkien, with his bombastic writing style, writing something like, “Above all others we honour them, who have faced the evil wrath of Sauron and not faltered”. As Erik indirectly says, that’s not _them who_ (that would be _those who_), but rather _them_ on its own, and then a relative clause beginning with a much more independent _who_ meaning itself “those who”.

Comment: @medica - With a comma, as depicted in my sentence 3) above, I'd regard it as borderline acceptable in a non-formal written context (e.g. a personal letter); without a comma, the construction is liable to confuse and is thus best avoided. I regard *correctness* as being a less useful concept than *appropriateness* for this kind of situation, because different contexts of usage, register and audience -- as well as whether we are considering speech or the written word -- have significant implications for acceptability.

Comment: @medica I think, to quote JL, one has to say 'It's grammatical, but that's the only good thing you can say about it'. It's an archaic construction: _God made him who had no sin to be sin_ (2 Corinthians 5:21, N(!?)IV). Holman updates to 'the One'. Fowler gives an example of the form

(*)“Do not follow he who breaks the law.” 

saying (I’m sure correctly) that the correct version is 

“Do not follow him who breaks the law.”

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think I read too much of the above. I agree with *Do not follow him who breaks the law.* But I can't understand *Do not follow them who break the law.* I clearly need more schooling. As for 2 Cor 5:21, there are so many translations of that, and they differ. JL would really be a good one for that (Do you know Koine Greek? I don't.)

Comment: @medica - Not a problem for me. You've done nothing that requires an apology.

Comment: I've just realised, Erik, that it would have been quite unsurprising to have heard something like 'Ah pity them {who / wot / wot ov / as 'av}  lost their money ...' hereabouts say 55 years ago. I've never tied in say 'God made him who had no sin to be sin' to these examples. They seem? are? miles apart in register. Perhaps the natives spoke a truer version than what we do.

Comment: I think the rules are different for restrictive and non-restrictive RCs, as JLawler pointed out. The OP's examples are are all restrictive. I think your interpretation will work but only if the clause is non-restrictive ...